# How to use CASE statement in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I am trying to use the `CASE` statement in SQL Server to solve an issue I have.

This is my sample data:

```
FY    COUNTRY   LAT         LON         CHECK       ID
------------------------------------------------------------
2013    MEX     35.85311    -118.1385   Y           80845
2013    USA     35.85311    -118.1385   Y           80845
```

Here is my `CASE` statement in SQL Server

```
SELECT 
    FY,
    LAT, LON, 
    CASE 
       WHEN COUNTRY = 'MEX' 
          THEN 'Y' 
    END AS MEX, 
    CASE 
       WHEN COUNTRY = 'USA' 
          THEN 'Y' 
    END AS USA, 
    ID
FROM 
    TEMP
```

My result:

```
FY      LAT         LON        MEX    USA   ID
---------------------------------------------------
2013    35.85311    -118.1385   Y   (null)  80845
2013    35.85311    -118.1385(null)   Y     80845
```

Is there a way to convert my result to:

```
FY      LAT         LON        MEX     USA        ID
--------------------------------------------------------
2013    35.85311    -118.1385   Y       Y         80845
```

Comment: what version of SQL server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `group by` and `max`:

```
select
    fy, lat, lon, 
    max(case when country = 'MEX' then 'Y' end) as mex, 
    max(case when country = 'USA' then 'Y' end) as usa, 
    id
from temp
group by
fy, lat, lon, id;
```

or may be using `PIVOT`:

```
select fy, lat, lon, id, mex, usa
from temp t
pivot ( max(check) for country in ([mex],[usa]) ) p;
```

Comment: @ GurV, wherever you are at, wherever you live, I would like to thank you so much for your help! It works just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

This is also referred to as a PIVOT statement

```
SELECT   FY, LAT, LON, ID, MEX, USA
FROM     TEMP t
PIVOT (
    MAX([CHECK])
    FOR [COUNTRY] IN([MEX],[USA])
) p
```

Comment: Thanks for your assistance!  Joe

Comment: This is the correct answer if you are on a 2008 or greater.

Answer (score 0):

CASE Statement with Syntex and example

**Syntex**
CASE expression

```
 WHEN value_1 THEN result_1

   WHEN value_2 THEN result_2

   ...
WHEN value_n THEN result_n



 ELSE result

END
```

**OR**

```
CASE
WHEN condition_1 THEN result_1
   WHEN condition_2 THEN result_2
   ...
WHEN condition_n THEN result_n
   ELSE result
END
```

**Example**

```
    SELECT contact_id,
CASE website_id
WHEN 1 THEN 'TechOnTheNet.com'
  WHEN 2 THEN 'CheckYourMath.com'
  ELSE 'BigActivities.com'
END
FROM contacts;
```

Or you could write the SQL statement using the CASE statement like this
   CASE

```
    WHEN website_id = 1 THEN 'TechOnTheNet.com'

  WHEN website_id = 2 THEN 'CheckYourMath.com'

  ELSE 'BigActivities.com'

END
```

FROM contacts;